# Check constraint vs proper lookup table

Tags: sql

I need to use sets in standard SQL. I need describe column type like selection from set of something `(Example Color=[Red, Green, Blue] )`. I can use check constrain or create lookup table with tree records - Red,Green,Blue. What are pluses and minuses of each method. I need to make this solution universal and use in much as possible SQL servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be universal then use a lookup table.

Check constraints aren't implemented fully in MySQL (the syntax is accepted but they aren't checked).

Another advantage of a lookup table is that it then becomes easier to provide an admin facility for people to add new options without having to dynamically rewrite all associated check constraints.

An advantage that check constraints can have over lookup tables is that the optimiser potentially can use contradiction detection however. In SQL Server a query for `WHERE Colour = 'Purple'` might not even read the table as SQL Server can tell at compile time that would not be possible as the check constraints prevents it.

Comment: "*not implemented fully*" is an understatement. The are simply not implemented at all in MySQL